# Do a sort of HEAC - High Efficiency Audio Codec exists?

Tags: audio, codec

As HEVC - High Efficiency Video Codec (h265) can be considered a a sort of upgrade of AVC - Advanced Video Codec (h264), is there a similar "upgraded" audio codec compared to AAC - Advanced Audio Codec? Specifically, I'm thinking of a codec that supports 3D audio and higher compression ratios.

Thanks for satisfying my curiosity!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [HE-AAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-Efficiency_Advanced_Audio_Coding) fits that bill.

> High-Efficiency Advanced Audio Coding (HE-AAC) is an audio coding
>   format for lossy data compression of digital audio defined as an
>   MPEG-4 Audio profile in ISO/IEC 14496-3. It is an extension of Low
>   Complexity AAC (AAC LC) optimized for low-bitrate applications such as
>   streaming audio. HE-AAC version 1 profile (HE-AAC v1) uses spectral
>   band replication (SBR) to enhance the compression efficiency in the
>   frequency domain. HE-AAC version 2 profile (HE-AAC v2) couples SBR
>   with Parametric Stereo (PS) to enhance the compression efficiency of
>   stereo signals. It is a standardized and improved version of the
>   AACplus codec.

As does [Opus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opus_(audio_format)).

> Opus is a lossy audio coding format developed by the Xiph.Org
>   Foundation and standardized by the Internet Engineering Task Force,
>   designed to efficiently code speech and general audio in a single
>   format, while remaining low-latency enough for real-time interactive
>   communication and low-complexity enough for low end ARM3
>   processors.[3][4] Opus replaces both Vorbis and Speex for new
>   applications, and several blind listening tests have ranked it higher
>   quality than any other standard audio format at any given bitrate
>   until transparency is reached, including MP3, AAC, and HE-AAC.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FFmpeg with the right libraries to encode H.265/HE-AAC version 2, this is the command I use for that kind of encoding:

`ffmpeg \
-i input.mp4 \
-c:v libx265 \
-preset medium \
-x265-params crf=28 \
-ar 48000 \
-ac 2 \
-c:a libfdk_aac \
-profile:a aac_he_v2 \
-b:a 64k \
-strict experimental \
output.mp4`

I have a cheat sheet for FFmpeg here:
https://github.com/rodrigopolo/cheatsheets/blob/master/ffmpeg.md